# Operations on Hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

Using Hashtable I want to have multiple objects mapped to the same key. E.g. Key is 'Age' and Values are ojects of struct 'Student'.

I suppose perceptually there will be a sort of linked list with Key acting as a 'Head'
**25->obj1->obj2->obj3**

### Here are my questions:

> > Is the above representation correct?
> >     If not, which data structure can be
> >     used for achieving the same?
> >
> > Can I look up for a specific field on the above data representation. e.g. One I reach the key 25, I look for the name **'Scott'** in the row. Will I be able to stop/ get a pointer to the object containing the field Scott?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed a webpage which made me think the way I did:
http://www.math.grin.edu/~walker/courses/153.sp02/lab-hashtables-inheritance.html

Here, the Hash Table seem to show the kind of concept I am referring to.

Can can i achieve something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using C#, the best option would probably be (which, essentially, is what you're proposing):

```
var collection = new Dictionary<Age, List<Student>>();
```

Assuming Age and Student are both types.

Comment: Why not use an `ISet` instead of `List`?

Comment: @Hamish - In this case, I'm using var to hold the value. I need concrete types on the right side of the assignment.

Comment: @Hamish it would depend completely on his implementation of student.  For instance 2 Students can have the same name.  On the converse he could use the ID of the student and compare the 2 values before inserting them.

Answer (score 3):

Only one value can be stored for a key. So how about `Hashtable<int, List<Student>>` ?

Comment: Hashtable isn't generic, Dictionary<key, List<value>> does the same and saves you some casting.

Comment: I have a type that I call Index that is essentially a wrapped version of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a collection of all the students at the time you want to create this data-structure, you could do

```
var lookUp = Students.ToLookUp (student => student.Age);
```

The disadvantage is that the `Lookup <K,V>` data-structure is immutable. If this is not an option, a `Dictionary<int, List<Student>>` structure might be more appropriate as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *wrong* data structure to use here, just some structures to store will be better suited for your needs depending on what you want to do with the results that are keyed on the age.

You indicated you wanted the ability to perform a lookup on the items based on name once you get the students that are a particular age.  In this case, your would want to have an `IDictionary<string, Student>` where the key is the first name of the Student.

Note, that this is a *highly* specialized structure here.  If it keeps expanding to where you need to search on other facets, you might want to take a look at other options, as the code required would grow pretty unmaintainable as your selection criteria grew.